# ItextPdf insert List of Objects into PDF | AcroField & List

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have created an invoice PDF template with predefined fields. I am able to populate simple text and number fields with `AcroFields` from ItextPdf.
My problem is that I have to **add a list of ItemObjects** the user bought into the same document at **PositionList**.
I can´t find a working solution tackling how to print a dynamic list into a AcroField or any kind of workaround. Im open for any hint or solution.

```
        form.setField("CONFIGID", configId);
        form.setField("SERVICEDATE", startDate);
        form.setField("USERINFO", userInfo);
        form.setField("PRICE_NET", String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(grossPrice * 0.8)));
        form.setField("GROSS", String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(grossPrice * 0.2)));
        form.setField("PRICE_GROSS", String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(grossPrice)));
```

[image: invoice.pdf]

Comment: Its not clear to me what you want to achieve. What kind of field type is your PositionList? Textfield? Then just concatenate your List into one string and add it. Or if it is a multiline text field add each item to one line. But that is just guessing. What are your ItemObjects ? Strings? Some objects? Too much information missing...

Comment: @Lonzak thank you for pointing that out. PositionList is a TextField but with this type i can´t insert lists. So I am asking more in general how I can insert a list into a pdf, it doesn´t have to mean that I want to use AcroFields for achieving that. The only thing I want to achieve is to insert a fully readable list at the place of PositionList including collumns.

Answer (score 0):

What is best for you depends on your requirements:

- should it still be editable or readonly?
- Are all options equal or do you want to select/highlight one?
- Do you later want to extract/analyze the content from the list (formfield vs. normal text)?
- ...

There are several possibilities to add a list where each has its own (dis)advantages:

1. Use a textfield with its `Multiline` flag set
2. Listbox (scrollable)
3. Dropdownbox
4. (non-formfield solution) normal Text

All of the above can be added with iText. See the following screenshot with the possibilities.
[image].